# Setting fbcon to use a specfic frame buffer device

Tags: linux, framebuffer

I am trying to display the output from and SDL based application on to a framebuffer device /dev/fb1. Fb1 is associated with a SM750 based card.

When I run my application, the output always appears on fb0 (which overwrites the ubuntu desktop whilst running.)

I know that fb1 is active, when I type in the following

```
sudo fbset -fb /dev/fb1 640x480-60
```

The display connected to the corresponding port is activated.

To run my application I have used the following command line:

```
SDL_FBDEV=/dev/fb1 SDL_VIDEODRIVER=xxx sudo ./SDLTimeOutput
```

Where xxx is directfb, fbcon, or svgalib. I have tried all 3, and get the same result each time.

Could some one please advise me on how I can set my application to display on fb1 rather than fb0.

Andrew